# How to figure out why is QtCreator underlining text red?

Tags: qt-creator

I probably did some typo, or something. It's not really important what's wrong with the code, what freaks me out is, that I can't get *any error message* explaining why it's underlined!

[image: image description]

The IDE doesn't show any explanation to the behavior, making the red underline feature pretty worthless, as many times it's just a false alarm regarding unfinished piece of code.

How can I find out why did QtCreator underline code?

Comment: with version of Qt-creator you use?

Comment: @MasihAkbari 3.5.81. I expect you to tell me why is that relevant for this question.

Comment: i was reading a bug report that fixed in version 2.6 i was going to compare with that version.

Comment: i dident notice that bug reproduced in version 3.5 at the end here is the [link](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-7374) and here is a feature request about [disabling syntax error highlighting](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-7552).

Comment: It's not bug! There is an error in the code, so it's highlighted. But there is no explanation **why the f\*\*k is it highlighted** - so I have to find the issue myself. That's the problem here, not a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mouse-over the red line, it should display a popup

Comment: I put it over the text and I also tried context menu but nothing... Maybe I was too impatient.

Comment: Confirmed, it appears if you wait for a while. You just mustn't move the mouse.